# How can I access the list from API to display data? (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, broadcastreceiver, fetch, postman

I have a `List` of cars that I am trying to display. The data needed is from postman and to access the car info I need to first access the list but I'm not sure how to do so. I'm also not sure how to call the car function I made, Ive searched for ways but no has worked.

here is how the data in postman looks:

```
{
    "listCar": [
        {
            "id": 204,
            "adTitle": "AdTitlecar",
            "adDate": "2019-11-07T11:52:40.0156875",
            "adPrice": 25.0,
            "category": "4X4",
            "categoryId": 7,
            "status": 1,
            "brandId": 1,
            "brand": "مرسيدس",
            "brandModelId": 6,
            "brandModel": "M300",
            "kilometer": 300.0,
            "modelYearId": 2,
            "modelYear": "2010",
            "fuelType": "بنزين",
            "carFeatureFuelId": 3,
            "gearType": "اوتوماتك",
            "carFeatureGearId": 2,
            "image": null,
            "vendorId": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 203,
            "adTitle": "AdTitlecar",
            "adDate": "2019-11-07T11:52:37.7771547",
            "adPrice": 25.0,
            "category": "4X4",
            "categoryId": 7,
            "status": 1,
            "brandId": 1,
            "brand": "مرسيدس",
            "brandModelId": 6,
            "brandModel": "M300",
            "kilometer": 300.0,
            "modelYearId": 2,
            "modelYear": "2010",
            "fuelType": "بنزين",
            "carFeatureFuelId": 3,
            "gearType": "اوتوماتك",
            "carFeatureGearId": 2,
            "image": null,
            "vendorId": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 202,
            "adTitle": "AdTitlecar",
            "adDate": "2019-11-07T11:52:35.5569602",
            "adPrice": 25.0,
            "category": "4X4",
            "categoryId": 7,
            "status": 1,
            "brandId": 1,
            "brand": "مرسيدس",
            "brandModelId": 6,
            "brandModel": "M300",
            "kilometer": 300.0,
            "modelYearId": 2,
            "modelYear": "2010",
            "fuelType": "بنزين",
            "carFeatureFuelId": 3,
            "gearType": "اوتوماتك",
            "carFeatureGearId": 2,
            "image": null,
            "vendorId": 1
        },

    ],
}
```

Here is my car Object I made:

```
object CarsListData {
    var id = 0
    var title = ""
    var date = ""
    var price = 0.0
    var category = ""
    var brand = ""
    var model = ""
    var distance = 0.0
    var year = ""
    var fuel = ""
    var gear = ""
}
```

here is how im fetching the data as `GET`:

```
 fun carsList(context: Context, complete: (Boolean) -> Unit) {

        val carList = object : JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, URL_CAR_LIST, null, Response.Listener { response ->
            try {
                CarsListData.id = response.getInt("id")
                CarsListData.title = response.getString("adTitle")
                CarsListData.date = response.getString("adDate")
                CarsListData.price = response.getDouble("adPrice")
                CarsListData.category = response.getString("category")
                CarsListData.brand = response.getString("brand")
                CarsListData.model = response.getString("brandModel")
                CarsListData.distance = response.getDouble("kilometer")
                CarsListData.year = response.getString("modelYear")
                CarsListData.fuel = response.getString("fuelType")
                CarsListData.gear = response.getString("gearType")
//                UserDataService.image = response.getString("image")
                val userDataChange = Intent(BROADCAST_USER_DATA_CHANGE)
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(userDataChange)
                complete(true)
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                Log.d("JSON", "EXC" + e.localizedMessage)
            }
        }, Response.ErrorListener {error ->
            Log.d("ERROR", "Could not login user: $error")
            complete(false)
        }) {
            override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            }

            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer $authToken")
                return headers
            }
        }
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(carList)
    }
```

here is how Im broadcasting the data in the listCarPage:

```
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(userDataChangeReciever,
            IntentFilter(BROADCAST_USER_DATA_CHANGE)
        )
    }

    private val userDataChangeReciever = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            carDetailsDate.text = CarsListData.date
            carDetailsTitle.text = CarsListData.title
            carDetailsCategory.text = CarsListData.category
            carDetailsPrice.text = CarsListData.price.toString()
            carDetailsDistance.text = CarsListData.distance.toString()
            cardetailsGear.text = CarsListData.gear
            carDetailsOil.text = CarsListData.fuel
            carDetailsYear.text = CarsListData.year
        }
    }
```

I tried accessing the "listCar" and nothing seems to work and I just dont feel like im doing this the right way so would appreciate any suggestions!

Edit-

CarAdapter code:

```
class CarAdapter(context: Context, cars: List<Cars>) : BaseAdapter() {

    val context = context
    val cars = cars

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val carsView: View

        carsView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cars_list, null)
        val carImage: ImageView = carsView.findViewById(R.id.carDetailsImage)
        val carTitle: TextView = carsView.findViewById(R.id.carDetailsTitle)
        val carCategory: TextView = carsView.findViewById(R.id.carDetailsCategory)
        val carPrice: TextView = carsView.findViewById(R.id.carDetailsPrice)
        val carDistance: TextView = carsView.findViewById(R.id.carDetailsDistance)
        val carDate: TextView = carsView.findViewById(R.id.carDetailsDate)
        val carGear: TextView = carsView.findViewById(R.id.cardetailsGear)
        val carYear: TextView = carsView.findViewById(R.id.carDetailsYear)
        val carOil: TextView = carsView.findViewById(R.id.carDetailsOil)

        val car = cars[position]

        carTitle.text = car.title
        carCategory.text = car.category
        carPrice.text = car.price
        carDistance.text = car.distance
        carDate.text = car.date
        carGear.text = car.gear
        carYear.text = car.year
        carOil.text = car.oil
        val resourceId = context.resources.getIdentifier(car.image, "drawable", context.packageName)
        carImage.setImageResource(resourceId)

        return carsView
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return cars[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return cars.count()
    }
}
```

here is the list of cars data :

```
class Cars(val date: String, val id: Int, val title: String, val image: String, val category: String, val price: String,val distance: String,val gear: String,val oil: String,val year: String) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return title
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code

```
 try {   
        val list: List<CarsListData> = ArrayList() 
        val listCar = response.getJSONArray("listCar ") 

             for (i in 0 until listCar.length()) {
                                                val carData=
                                                listCar.getJSONObject(i)
        CarsListData.id = response.getInt("id")
                        CarsListData.title = carData.getString("adTitle")
                        CarsListData.date = carData.getString("adDate")
                        CarsListData.price = carData.getDouble("adPrice")
                        CarsListData.category = carData.getString("category")
                        CarsListData.brand = carData.getString("brand")
                        CarsListData.model = carData.getString("brandModel")
                        CarsListData.distance = carData.getDouble("kilometer")
                        CarsListData.year = carData.getString("modelYear")
                        CarsListData.fuel = carData.getString("fuelType")
                        CarsListData.gear = carData.getString("gearType")
    list.add(CarsListData)
                                            }
val userDataChange = Intent(BROADCAST_USER_DATA_CHANGE)
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(userDataChange)
                complete(true)
         catch (e: JSONException) {
                        Log.d("JSON", "EXC" + e.localizedMessage)
                    }
```

Here is broadcasting the data in the listCarPage:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(userDataChangeReciever,
            IntentFilter(BROADCAST_USER_DATA_CHANGE)
        )
    }

private val userDataChangeReciever = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
// Here you can loop through the list 
    val data = list[0] // just example
        carDetailsDate.text = data.date
        carDetailsTitle.text = data.title
        carDetailsCategory.text = data.category
        carDetailsPrice.text = data.price.toString()
        carDetailsDistance.text = data.distance.toString()
        cardetailsGear.text = data.gear
        carDetailsOil.text = data.fuel
        carDetailsYear.text = data.year
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I call this function in my CarsListActivity now? also do I delete the Broadcast val I had? is it not needed?

Comment: The list[0] is giving an unresolved error what should I replace it with? @Muhammad Adil

Comment: Do i replace it with the carsList function? since its never used

Comment: I already said make "val list: MutableList<List<CarsListData>> = ArrayList() " global variable in your class and remove it from try catch

Comment: I did exactly like your suggestion but I have an error I will update my code